# Show that the elliptic curves $y^2=x^3+ax+b$ and $y^2=x^3+ac^{-4}x+bc^{-6}$ are isomorphic?

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves

How to see the elliptic curves $y^2=x^3+ax+b$ and $y^2=x^3+ac^{-4}x+bc^{-6}$ are isomorphic ?

Here $a,~b,~,c \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $c \neq 0$.

If I scale $x$ and $y$ by $(x,y,z) \mapsto (c^2x,c^3y,z)$ in the 2nd curve, we get
$$ (c^3y)^2=(c^2x)^3+ac^{-4} \cdot c^2x+bc^{-6}.$$ Simplifying , we get $$c^6y^2=c^6x^3+ac^{-2}x+bc^{-6}.$$

Cancelling out by $c^6$ both sides, we get $$y^2=x^3+ac^{-8}+bc^{-12}.$$

So not isomorphic if my calculation is correct.

**Edit:** I got it from the below comment, the map works for opposite way to my above calculation

Comment: Your map should go the other way round.

Comment: @user10354138, oh, i got it. Thanks

Comment: A little related note. The standard numbering for a Weierstrass equation $y^2 + a_1 xy + a_3 y = x^3 + a_2 x^2 + a_4x + a_6$ gives labels $a_i$ so that replacing $a_i$ by $u^i a_i$ gives an isomorphic curve.